# How to get Selenium C# control names for reporting

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I'm wanting to report a line every time my selenium based automation framework clicks on a control. My object repository is storing individual controls like this:

```
public static By ExampleControl = By.CssSelector("sidemenu > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a");
```

Each time my click method fires I want it to log something like "User clicked on: ExampleControl" However, when I do this I'm getting "User clicked on: sidemenu > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a". Here is my current code:

```
public void Click(OpenQA.Selenium.By Control)
{
    WaitForControlClickable(Control);
    TestInitiator.driver.FindElement(Control).Click();
    reporter.LogInfo("User clicked on: " + Control);
}
```

How do I get that Control in the log to show the name of the control rather than the css selector (or whatever other method I'm using to identify the object)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend a wrapper class to do this:

```
public class ByControlWithName
{
    public OpenQA.Selenium.By Control { get; set; }
    public string ControlName { get; set; }

    public ByControlWithName(OpenQA.Selenium.By ctl, string name)
    {
        this.Control = ctl;
        this.ControlName = name;
    }
}
```

Here's your static call:

```
public static ByControlWithName ExampleControl = new ByControlWithName(By.CssSelector("sidemenu > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a"), "ExampleControl");
```

And the updated function:

```
public void Click(ByControlWithName Control)
{
    WaitForControlClickable(Control.Control);
    TestInitiator.driver.FindElement(Control.Control).Click();
    reporter.LogInfo("User clicked on: " + Control.ControlName);
}
```

Comment: I tried this approach but my script is now throwing an exception: OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Comment: @Staindz - i had to change it so the element's information is grabbed prior to clicking...after the click is too late because it has refreshed the page by then

Comment: So it took me a minute to wrap my head around what your code was doing but now i understand why it's not working for me. I access  most objects through xpath and CSS selector.  I have a repository of objects and they have "names" but when i refer to that object it gives me me whatever selenium is using to find the object on the page (the xpath, name, id, or css selector).

i already have assigned a name to this object, i just need it printed in my logs. In my original post you can see an example of how i store my objects, with "ExampleControl" being the name i want passed in to my logs.

Comment: I think you need a 2nd parameter And pass in the nameof example to it each time you call it

Comment: That is also the only solution i've been able to think of as well, which unfortunately, isn't a clean way of doing it since this is called constantly throughout all of my tests. I appreciate you looking through this with me though.

Comment: @Staindz - made another recommendation

Answer (score 0):

Try using `nameof()`, e.g.:

`reporter.LogInfo("User clicked on: " + nameof(Control));`

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, i tried implementing this and ended up getting: "User clicked on: Control" rather than the actual name of the control.